# Hiding information on a physical monitor

Tags: security, display

I am tired of people looking at my computer display screen when I am using the computer and seeing my secrets and confidential information etc. How do I prevent people peeking over my shoulder from seeing private information I am working on, for example a work document?

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying encrypted information? I mean if it is encrypted you can not read it. I minimize windows with private information when i don't want people to see it. I guess I don't really understand your question. You could buy some privacy foil which minimizes the angle from which you can read anything, so you have to be right in front of the display to be able to see what is displayed.

Comment: I am working with private information and people see it. How to make the information somehow invisible to others?

Comment: I guess what you are asking for is not possible unless we are cyborgs and have an implanted crypto chip which decrypts the displayed garbage. The way to go is using privacy sensible applications which only display what is needed and if sensible information needs to be displayed your only possibility is to put the display in a place where only those who have to work with it can see the data.

Comment: Changing your desk's position or some kind of eyeglass display would make more sense.  Like the others here, I don't get how you would be able to read encrypted data.

Comment: Use a screen locker when someone is within viewing range of your monitor...

Comment: Why do you try to reopen this?  This can not be done from within the operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3M manufactures a product called Privacy Filter which is a membrane attached to your monitor that will make it visible only for the very specific angle where the user is expected to be. I have never used this device and cannot testify for its effectiveness, but there are several promotional videos and reviews on YouTube demonstrating how it works.

http://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/All-3M-Products/Privacy-Screen-Protectors/Privacy-Products/?N=5002385+8710873+8711017+8725356+3294857497&rt=r3

Other brands make those too, you might want to look into those as well.

Other than that, I can only think of VR devices or some sort of software that will shuffle display data in a way that can only be decoded by an active pair of glasses. Technically feasible, but I am not sure someone has already done it.

Comment: My coworker is using one and I can't see anything on his screen.

Comment: I've seen people use such filters in trains and can attest that I couldn't see anything from the neighbouring seat. (I don't know which brand they were using).